# "zusammenschweißen" ohne Objekt verwenden

Tags: verb, usage

Aus dem [Spiegel-Online](http://www.spiegel.de/gesundheit/ernaehrung/2015-gute-vorsaetze-trailrunning-bogenschiessen-trampolin-a-1010621.html):

> Auch das Team spricht für den Sport. Es springt zwar fast immer nur einer. Die anderen aber stehen um das Gerät, um ihn im Ernstfall aufzufangen. Man muss einander vertrauen. **Das schweißt zusammen.**

[Diesem](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/zusammenschwei%C3%9Fen) und [diesem](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/zusammenschwei%C3%9Fen) Wörterbuch zufolge ist **zusammenschweißen** exklusiv transitiv. Wie kann man dann den zitierten Satz grammatikalisch rechtfertigen?

Comment: Ich *vermute*, dass es sich einfach um eine Ellipse handelt: Das schweißt **[das Team]** zusammen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ein transitives Verb kann aus **stilistischen** Gründen ohne („ausdrückliches“) Objekt stehen - das ändert dann nichts daran, dass sich das Verb immer noch auf ein Objekt bezieht. Nur ist es dann am Leser, das Objekt aus dem Kontext zu ergänzen.

Hier geht es durchweg um ein Team, das auch als Objekt zu „zusammenschweißen” ergänzt werden muss. Team, Mannschaft oder eine andere Bezeichnung für eine Personengruppe fungieren typischerweise als Objekt, wenn „[zusammenschweißen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zusammenschweiszen)“ im Sinne von „den Zusammenhalt innerhalb einer Gruppe verstärken/erhöhen“ verwendet wird.

Grammatikalisch falsch wäre es m.E. nur, wenn kein Objekt aus dem Kontext erschlossen werden kann.